# Association Reputation Bonus on preexisting sites

Tags: support, reputation, association

I have a couple of questions about reputation. In order to receive the +100 site association rep, does one need to earn the reputation entirely on one website, or can it be earned accross multiple(For example, 50 on Meta, 100 on StackOverflow, and 50 on Code Review)?

When one does accrue 200 reputation, is the site bonus awarded to accounts on exchanges which had already existed before earning the reputation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to accrue 200 reputation on a single site.

When you do, the association bonus will be applied to any linked account on any of the sites where you have an account. If you create a new account on a site you'll immediately receive the association bonus.

Comment: The last part isn't quite right.  Earning 200 rep on one site doesn't give you an extra 200 rep on that site (moving you from 200 to 300 right away).  If you earn 200 rep on one site, you get a bonus on *all other* sites.  Then, if you earn 200 rep (past the association bonus) on any of those other sites, you'll earn the 100 rep association bonus on the first site you passed 200 rep on.

Comment: You reached 200 rep on both SO and meta right around the same time.  Each of which earned you the association bonus on the other site.

Comment: @Servy That directly contradicts what happened to me, at least. I hit 200 on Gaming, and got the association bonus on every site I had an account on, including Gaming itself, without having hit 200 anywhere else. Even after the bonus, it was my only 200, at least according to a quick check I just conducted.